# Python rpm must be installed on a different path

Tags: python, linux, yum

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   56192 Aug  3 04:20 python36u-3.6.2-1.ius.centos7.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  204112 Aug  3 04:20 python36u-devel-3.6.2-1.ius.centos7.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 9689852 Aug  3 04:20 python36u-libs-3.6.2-1.ius.centos7.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1841528 Feb  3  2017 python36u-pip-9.0.1-1.ius.centos7.noarch.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  663324 Mar 22  2017 python36u-setuptools-33.1.1-1.ius.centos7.noarch.rpm



yum install *
```

The default path is installed as /usr/bin/python3.6, but I would like to have it installed in the /usr/local/python/.

Comment: Maybe see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385390/specify-the-install-location-for-a-relocatable-rpm-using-yum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract files from these rpm packages via `rpm2cpio` and move them manually:

```sh
rpm2cpio your_package.rpm | cpio -id ./some_folder
```

Then you can see all files the package contains. After that move them where you need.